# how to import an local static image in vuex store

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vue-component, vuex

I dispatch an action in vuex to fetch an array image urls binding to the swiper or carousel, but now I want to add a local static image to the array,how to write it?

How can I do in the store or any other method?

```
actions:{
getBanner({commit, state}){
    axios(url).then(data =>{
      commit('setImageArr',data)
    })
  }
}

mutations:{
  setImageArr(state,arr){
    state.arr = arr
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

add a mutation:

```
actions:{
getBanner({commit, state}){
    axios(url).then(data =>{
      commit('setImageArr',data)
    })
  }
}

mutations:{
  setImageArr(state,arr){
    state.arr = arr
  },
  addImg ({arr},{url}) {
    arr.push(url)
  }
}
```

usage:

```
this.$store.commit('addImg',{url:'your img url'})
```